# How can I retrieve the query parameters passed from the URL?

Tags: 8

In Drupal 8, `$_GET` does not return the query parameter I am expecting to get. With the following code, I get `1` all the times, even when I expect to get `2`.

```php
namespace Drupal\newday\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class NewdayController extends ControllerBase {

  public function new() {
    $day = [
      "#markup" => \Drupal::request()->query->get('id'),
    ];

    return $day;
  }

}
```

How do I get the correct query parameter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The request is being cached, you need to tell the system to vary by the query arg:

```
$day = [
    '#markup' => \Drupal::request()->query->get('id'),
    '#cache' => [
        'contexts' => ['url.query_args:id'],
    ],
];
```

You need to rebuild cache after altering the render array to see the effects.

If you're not familiar with it already, [Cacheability of render arrays](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays) is worth a read.