# How do I retrieve the query parameters from a path?

Tags: 8

How do I retrieve the query parameters from a path. Here's my path:

> /search?keys=hello

Here is what I've tried:

```
$test1 = \Drupal::request()->request->get('name');
$test2 = \Drupal::request()->query->get('name');
$test3 = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
$test4 = \Drupal::request()->server->get('REQUEST_METHOD');
$test5 = \Drupal::request()->query->get('q');
$test6 = \Drupal::request()->request->get('keys');
$test7 = \Drupal::request()->query->get('keys');
$test8 = \Drupal::request()->query->get('destination');
$test9 = \Drupal::request()->request->all();
$test10 = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
```

Here are the results:

> Test 1: NULL
>
> Test 2: NULL
>
> Test 3: '/search'
>
> Test 4: 'GET'
>
> Test 5: NULL
>
> Test 6: NULL
>
> Test 7: NULL
>
> Test 8: NULL
>
> Test 9: array ( )
>
> Test 10: '/search'

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 15):

This is a [duplicate](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207044/how-to-get-post-and-get-parameters).  If you look at the [change log](https://www.drupal.org/node/2150267), there's a beautiful example for how to retrieve $_GET and $_POST variables.

I have tested locally at /search?keys=hello and

```
\Drupal::request()->query->get('keys');
```

works, as well as

```
\Drupal::request()->get('keys');
```

I tested your custom block and it works fine.  Have you tried clearing cache?

Update:

If it is caching, you can set your block to not cache, since it's a search block.  Or you can set it to cache for [each set of parameters](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231953/get-in-drupal-8/231954#231954).  Thanks @clive for the link.

Comment: I'm running the code from inside a custom block. Maybe the block gets cached, and my code does not run?

Comment: Yes, I have tested your code and it's working fine for me.  Do you know how to clear the cache?

Comment: Definitely @24ma13wg, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231953/get-in-drupal-8/231954#231954 for an example to fix it

Answer (score 13):

You were close. All you need to do is get:

```
$keys = \Drupal::request()->get('keys');
```

Here is an example of me using it:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_views_view()
 * @param $variables
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['id'] == 'acquia_search' && $variables['display_id'] == 'results') {
    $variables['get']['keywords'] = Xss::filter(\Drupal::request()->get('keywords'));
    $variables['get']['sort_by'] = Xss::filter(\Drupal::request()->get('sort_by'));
    $variables['get']['sort_order'] = Xss::filter(\Drupal::request()->get('sort_order'));

    if (!Unicode::strlen($variables['get']['sort_by'])) {
      $variables['get']['sort_by'] = 'search_api_relevance';
    }

    if (!Unicode::strlen($variables['get']['sort_order'])) {
      $variables['get']['sort_order'] = 'DESC';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get `NULL` for that?

Comment: @dbj44 did you add `use Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss; use Drupal\Component\Utility\Unicode;` at the top?

Answer (score 11):

The problem was the block was cached.  See Clive's [comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231953/get-in-drupal-8/231954#231954):

```
public function build() {
  $test = \Drupal::request()->query->get('keys');
  return array(
    '#markup' => $test,
    '#cache' => array(
      'contexts' => array(
        'url.query_args:keys',
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```