# .htaccess rewrite doesn't work

Tags: 8, .htaccess

I have custom module with page at `/page` wich expects `$_GET['id']` to do it's job.

Here's `.htaccess` rewrite rule that works on empty website

```
RewriteRule category+/(.*)$ page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

On Drupal 8 I suppose that line should be

```
RewriteRule category+/(.*)$ page?id=$1 [L]
```

but it gives me 404 Error when i visit `/category/5`

Comment: In a custom module you could simply add a route for `/category/{id}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rewrite rule will not work because page is not a valid path on the server. By default Drupal rewrites all requests into index.php. When you rewrite to page apache will expect a path page on the server.

This is not quite the right way to accomplish what you are trying to do in Drupal. However you can achieve what you are trying to do with the following

```
RewriteRule category+/(.*)$ page?id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

That will redirect category/5 to page?id=5 and you will get 5 in $_GET['id']

Check these out as well

https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/content-paths.html

[How do I retrieve the query parameters from a path?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232292/how-do-i-retrieve-the-query-parameters-from-a-path)