# How can I have default field values for the node add form as arguments in the URL?

Tags: 8, nodes, routes

I have a path in **drupal 6**, which allow me to add new content with 2 fields completed. For example, path `node/add/my_content_type/4/6` means that I am on page `/node/add/my_content_type`, and first field has value "Philip" and second field has value "Oleg". Those names are in database, because user put them in in another content type.

I try to do the same in **Drupal 8**, but I cannot put arguments after /mycontent_type/. So right now, on the /node/add/my_content_type I see a form with fields, I can select names in input select, but nothing shows when I put more arguments in url.

I will give an example:

I have a module with students and school trip. On custom content **"students"**, I add students names in text input. Those names are saved in database.

Let's say, that my second content type is **"trip"**.
I have a function, which allow me to add a trip, when students names are given. I can simply click add content 'trip' and select names in select fields, but I want to make it more simple and redirect to page /node/add/trip/4/6 where 4 is id of "Philip" and 6 is id of "Oleg". In this way I have a form with to fields already completed. It is posible in drupal 6, but no in drupal 8. Have can i do that?

I think that one of the problem could be the fact, that Drupal 8 require field "Title". So I have to modify url a little bit /node/add/trip/**??TITLE??**/4/6.

I need exactly this -> https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2020-04-27/webform-field-default-value-from-url
but for custom content :)

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!   Regarding the title field problem there's [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel). Getting the values from a URL query strings should be feasible pretty easily from a `hook_form_alter` implementation. So please try this: Create a custom module to implement `hook_form_alter`, learn how to target the desired form, learn how to set default values to existing elements, try to retrieve URL query parameters, and the set them as default values.

Comment: If anything doesn't work on the way, feel free to ask another reproducible, narrowly-scoped and detailed question including what you've tried yourself so far and what exactly didn't work as expected. Many thanks

Comment: I cannot retrieve URL parameters.

Comment: Okay, then please add the code that's not working to the question. And also please read https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/232292/15055 and explain what exactly is unclear with the given answers. Many thanks

Comment: in which function in module should I implement above code to get url? I am confused. I tried with /Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameters() but it doesn't print any parameters which I was looking for

Comment: `Array ( [#markup] => [#cache] => Array ( [contexts] => Array ( [0] => url.query_args:keys ) ) )` this is after print result from first function in above link

Comment: and `\Drupal::request()->query->all()` gives empty Array

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

in .module, hook_form_after()

```
$value = \Drupal::request()->query->get('q');
$value = Html::escape($value);
$form['student']['widget']['#default_value'] = [0 => $value];
```

with url /node/add/trip?q=6, where 6 is id of student Oleg